# How to evaluate a string which has the conditon expression vba

Tags: vba, excel

How can I evaluate a string like `"3>=5"` ?

I know I can split the numbers and conditions but then I would have to test for all conditions like `>=`,`=`,`<=`,`>`,`<`, ..... is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Application.Evaluate("3>=5")` is one way within VBA. (It's actually a remarkably comprehensive expression parser.)

In general it returns a `Variant`: in this particular guise it returns a VT_BOOL type which is `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `debug.print`:

```
Sub Testings()
    Debug.Print 3 >= 5
    Debug.Print 3 <= 5
End Sub
```

Will give:

```
False
True
```

This will print straight to the locals window

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `Application.Evaluate` unless your expressions continue to be small. When exceeding 250 characters `Application.Evaluate` will start to throw a wobbly!

I made `stdLambda` from [`stdVBA`](http://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA) project for this job:

```
Debug.Print stdLambda.Create("3 >=5").Run()    '=> True
Debug.Print stdLambda.Create("$1 >=5").Run(3)  '=> True
```